# UnderscoreJS - how to get first instance of value from the array of objects?

Tags: underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

In my array, I have no.of instance label with `code`. But i required just one from the first instance. I used the `find` method. But i am getting error.

here is my try:

```
var ob = {
    "name" : [
        {"code" : ""},
        {"code" : "1"},
        {"code" : "1"},
        {"code" : "1"},
        {"code" : "1"}
    ]
}

var code = _.find(ob.name, "code");
console.log(code); //error as "undefined is not a function"
```

the method which is use here is wrong? can any one guide me the correct one please?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c93asfed/)

Comment: You either need to pass a function as the second argument to `_.find`. What did you think would a string do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the first element from the array, use `_.first()`:

```
var code = _.first(ob.name).code;
```

Or

```
var code = _(ob.name).pluck('code').first();
```

If you want to get non-empty first element, use `filter` to filter out the empty elements.

```
_(ob.name).pluck('code').filter(function (e) { return !!e; }).first();
```

Comment: in case if i decide to check 2 property how can i handle that? example ({"code" : "1", sec:"1"}).. do i need to write 2 return functions or i can accommodate with one?

Comment: In that case, omit `pluck` function. Then you will get the each object that has two fields. You can use the property in the `filter` function.